# Which Field Would You Use to Represent a Group Larger than $\aleph _1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, cardinals

I understand that in representation theory we try to understand a group $G$ by studying the homomorphisms $\rho\  \colon G \to $ GL$(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space over some field. I believe complex numbers, adic numbers and finite fields are popular because we already understand the linear groups over these fields (though I really only have first-hand experience with the complex numbers). Suppose $G$ was simply "too large" to be a matrix group over $\mathbb C$ say. This can occur since the cardinality of GL$_n(\mathbb C)$ is equal to that of $\mathbb C$. If the cardinality of the group is larger than $\aleph _1$ we cannot hope to get a faithful (injective) representation.

What would be the better idea then, to let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector-space, or to use some field of higher cardinality? I imagine the first is the answer, since we also know a lot about infinite dimensional complex vector spaces, from Functional Analysis. But if you had to choose a larger field for some reason while keeping the vector space dimension finite, which field would be a good choice?

Comment: Note that you probably want $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$, the cardinality of the reals, here and not $\aleph_1$; the two of course aren't _necessarily_ equal...

Comment: Adjoin to $\Bbb{C}$ $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ algebraically independent transcendental elements, and take an algebraic closure of the resulting field? That field has no (obviously useful) topology, so may prove to be disappointing for doing analysis, but rep theory may work. At least you can define the set of algebraic functions, which still gives you some interesting representations :-)

Comment: @ Steven: HURR DURR ;-)

Comment: Do we know how to represents groups of size exactly $\aleph_1$?